# Elementwise operation on a 2D array

Tags: python

I'm trying to perform different operations on the two columns of a 2D array.

I have the following data into python...

```
[[ 0.  19.4]
 [ 0.5 19.2]
 [ 1.  19.8]
...
 [359 16. ]
 [359.5  16.2]]
```

I want to perform the following operation on every three rows;
for column 1: mean of the 3 values
for column 2: max of the 3 values
print this as a new array.

The result should look like this...

```
[[0.5 19.8]
 [....]
```

Thank you.

Comment: hey @user1606941 Welcome to StackOverflow. Please try to attempt your assignment questions on your own. Feel free to reach out to the community after explaining your thought process.

Comment: Try `array.max(axis=???)` figure out the axis param if you can.